# Python - Regex - from Xpath - TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, regex, xpath

The following code downloads a webpage, finds and element then runs a regular expression to parse a number out of the string.  It seems to work on my python 3.7 test system but not my python 3.5.  I am downloading a webpage, finding a text block using Xpath.  The xpath returns something like 'International (21)' or 'Books (99)'    I want to extract out the number, the 21 or 99.

In python 3.5 I get back  '***TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable.'***

I am not convinced the error is the differences in versions but that that is the only known diff.   The xpath seems to be working as it returns '**<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(14, 18), match='(21)'>'** when I print CountObj.

Is there a tweak I should make for python 3.5, is there a better way to code this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url); #Download the URL passed from mysql

CatAndCount =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2 [@class="searchResultsTitle"]').text 
 # the above line returns with a name and value like 'International (21)'

CountObj = re.search("\((.*?)\)",CatAndCount)  # look for the number, 21 in example
print (CountObj) # for testing
CountVal=CountObj[1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the [`group()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) method on the `re.MatchObject` with the number of captured group as the parameter to get that (blank or 0 for the whole match). So, to get the first captured group:

```
CountObj.group(1)
```

**Edit:**

If you have multiple captured groups, and want them all, then use `groups()` method to get them as a tuple e.g.:

```
CountObj.groups()
```

Or if you want specific ones e.g. the 1st and 4th captured group, use `group()` like below to get a tuple of the asked ones:

```
CountObj.group(1, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks.. when i did CountObj[1] vs CountObj[0] it was to get back the value  21 vs (21).  Is that what the group method is for? Or is this to handle the fact that the regular expression could return multiple results.  In my example it only returns one but i realize the regular expression could have multiple results

Answer (score 0):

This TypeError occur because of the lower version, such as below **Python Version 3.6**

What worked for me on version **3.5** was  using **.group(index)**  to access a specific group captured rather than accessing directly.

**Example:**

```py
# Capture Group
result = re.search(regex_pattern, target_text) 

# Insert index inside group to access a specific group captured
result.group(insert_index)
```